# display input type=file at multiple place in a form

Tags: javascript, html

In my form there are several places where I need to upload image & display the same
so how can I do the same please help

```js
function previewImage(){
    var file = document.getElementById("file").files;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(event){
        document.getElementById("display").setAttribute("src", event.target.result);
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0])
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<img id="display" class="w-50">
```

the html code is multiple time in my code calling the same function but it display only at first input field.

Comment: If the problem is related to having multiple `<input>` elements, why doesn't the example shown have multiple `<input>` elements?  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  At a glance, if those `<input>` elements *all have the same `id`* then that would certainly cause problems, since `id` needs to be unique.

Comment: `document.getElementById("display")` gets only the first occurrence. You need to select all elements with, say, `document.querySelectorAll('.display')` and then loop over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get current file input using `event.target` and to write the result to `<img>` which is next element you can use `thisElement.nextElementSibling`

```js
function previewImage() {
  var thisElement = event.target
  var file = thisElement.files;
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    thisElement.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("src", event.target.result);
    // hide the input
    thisElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0])
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<img class="display w-50">

<br>
<input type="file" id="file2" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<img class="display w-50">
```

Comment: Thanks your code actually do what I wanted to do but can you hide the input field after displaying the image

Comment: to hide, add `thisElement.style.display = 'none';` look the code in answer

Comment: how can i change the uploaded file